# How to group and count with MongoDB aggregation

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have a collection with different documents and their status. How can I display the status and number of each document?

```
[{
        "documentAStatus": "OPEN",
        "documentBStatus": "DONE",
        "documentCStatus": "APPROVED"
    },
    {
        "documentAStatus": "CANCELLED",
        "documentBStatus": "PHASE_OUT",
        "documentCStatus": "APPROVED"
    },
    {
        "documentAStatus": "CANCELLED",
        "documentBStatus": "DONE",
        "documentCStatus": "APPROVED"
    }
]
```

I would like to have such an output:

```
[{
    "documentAStatus": [{
            "OPEN": 1
        },
        {
            "CANCELLED": 2
        }
    ],
    "documentBStatus": [{
            "DONE": 2
        },
        {
            "PHASE_OUT": 1
        }
    ],
    "documentCStatus": [{
        "APPROVED": 3
    }]

}]
```

I've tried grouping, but the result is not as expected.

```
[{
    $unwind: '$documentAStatus'
}, {
    $group: {
        _id: {
            _id: '$_id',
            package: 'documentAStatus',
            status: '$documentAStatus'
        },
        count: {
            $sum: 1
        }
    }
}]
```

Does someone have a hint please?

Comment: Are you using any programming language?

Comment: Yes, Java Spring boot. But first I will test this on mongoDB compass if it's possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this:

```js
db.myCollection.aggregate([
    {
        $facet: {
            "documentAStatus": [
                {
                    $group: {
                        _id: "$documentAStatus",
                        count: { $sum: 1 }
                    }
                },
                {
                    $addFields: {
                        array: [{ k: "$_id", v: "$count" }]
                    }
                },
                {
                    $replaceRoot: {
                        newRoot: { $arrayToObject: "$array" }
                    }
                }
            ],
            "documentBStatus": [
                {
                    $group: {
                        _id: "$documentBStatus",
                        count: { $sum: 1 }
                    }
                },
                {
                    $addFields: {
                        array: [{ k: "$_id", v: "$count" }]
                    }
                },
                {
                    $replaceRoot: {
                        newRoot: { $arrayToObject: "$array" }
                    }
                }
            ],
            "documentCStatus": [
                {
                    $group: {
                        _id: "$documentCStatus",
                        count: { $sum: 1 }
                    }
                },
                {
                    $addFields: {
                        array: [{ k: "$_id", v: "$count" }]
                    }
                },
                {
                    $replaceRoot: {
                        newRoot: { $arrayToObject: "$array" }
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    }
])
```

Output:

```js
{
    "documentAStatus" : [
        {
            "OPEN" : 1
        },
        {
            "CANCELLED" : 2
        }
    ],
    "documentBStatus" : [
        {
            "DONE" : 2
        },
        {
            "PHASE_OUT" : 1
        }
    ],
    "documentCStatus" : [
        {
            "APPROVED" : 3
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: I will improve the query in next edit if posible.

Comment: Perfect !!! I don't know this facet yet. still has to learn a lot.

Comment: Neither did i. But gave it a try for first time. Thanks i learnt something!